# Create new polygon files from existing vector layer in R

Tags: r, polygon, rgdal

I have an existing vector shapefile with all the counties in the United States (called counties.shp) I also have a dataset that contains many species-county presence data points (species.csv) which looks something like this:

```
 GEOID  county    state         Species 
1: 21007 Ballard Kentucky     plant1
2: 21007 Ballard Kentucky     plant2
3: 21007 Ballard Kentucky     plant3
4: 21007 Ballard Kentucky     plant4 
5: 21017 Bourbon Kentucky     plant5
```

**I'd like to create a new polygon for each species that includes all of the counties that they are paired with in the species.csv file.** Each row is a unique species-county combination, so both counties and species are repeated throughout that file, yet I'd like to get a single polygon file for each species. There are several thousand species, so I'd like to have a way to do this all at once and compile the resulting polygons in a relatively neat way so I can easily use them for zonal statistics.

I'm imagining this is a somewhat simple task, but I'm completely new to GIS in R.

Comment: what do you mean for "new polygon", a multipolygon of the counties? a convex hull? a new file?

Comment: Do you know the basics of spatial data in R, using the `sf` package? eg how to read shapefiles, plot them, inspect them etc?

Comment: The first two rows you listed don't look a "unique species-county" - is row 2 meant to say "plant2"?

Comment: @ElioDiaz a multipolygon is what I'm after.

Comment: @Spacedman I've been using `rgdal` instead of `sf` but I've been able to read shapefiles and rasters and plot them using that. And yes, that was a typo, thanks for the catch I've corrected the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach filters the county polygons and them puts them together using lapply to iterate for each plant

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)

nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

plants = c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4")
# sample the counties twice to get more than one plant by county
plants_by_county = data.frame(county = sample(nc$NAME, 200, replace = T), plant =  sample(plants, 200, replace = T))

# data frame looks like this
print(plants_by_county)
          county plant
1         Yancey    p4
2          Davie    p2
3       Buncombe    p2
4       Alamance    p1

plant_multipolygons = lapply(plants, function(x) {
  nc %>%
    filter(NAME %in% plants_by_county$county[plants_by_county$plant == x]) %>% # filter counties
    select(geometry) %>%
    summarise() %>% # comment out summarise to get single polygons
    mutate(plant = x) })

plant_multipolygons = do.call(rbind, plant_multipolygons) # bind them into a data.frame

tm_shape(plant_multipolygons) + tm_polygons() + tm_facets("plant")
```

[image]

Comment: I think I understand most of this and have edited it appropriately, but I'm still getting an error message `Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'select': no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector')" ` Do I need to change the word "geometry" to something else?

Comment: you must transform your `spatialPolygons` object to `sf` with `st_as_sf(your_polygon_object)`

Comment: I've done that, now I'm getting a new error: `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"sf"’ `

Comment: pass `dplyr::select()` to instantiate properly

Comment: It's running, but the warning message concerns me: `although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_union assumes that they are planar` I think that will likely mess up the zonal statistics I try to calculate next...

Comment: you have 2 options: stick with `sf` which calculates `st_area` from a EPSG:4326 CRS and returns ellipsoidal area in m²; or use a projected CRS such as UTM or lambert

Comment: I think sticking with this process should work as long as I can figure out how to make sure my rasters are in the same CRS. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I just updated R (now version 4.1.0) and all of a sudden this code is running VERY SLOWLY - it used to take about 3 minutes to run, now it takes upwards of 2 hours... Any idea why this happened?